# How to get the distinct values in a column as well as total count using spring jpa pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to select list of unique values of column C and the corresponding count as well. My code is as following

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT t.C FROM table t WHERE t.param = :param order by t.C",
        countQuery = "SELECT count(DISTINCT t.C) FROM table t WHERE t.param = :param")
    Page<String> findUniqueWithCountPagination(Pageable pageable,
        @Param("param") String param);
```

I am getting the error `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified`. When I enable the show-sql property, I noticed that Spring is adding another column U automatically to the order by filter. U is a timestamp column in table t.

How to remove the unnecessary field U in the order by? if that is not possible, is there any other way to write the query for my requirement?

Comment: Can you please paste the generated query you have mentioned?

Comment: `select distinct TOP(?) t0_.C as col_0_0_ from dbo.t t0_ where
t0_.param=?  order by t0_.C, to_.U desc`

Comment: Won't this kind of a query be better for your use case - `SELECT t.C, COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE t.param = '1' GROUP BY t.C order by t.C`? (This is Oracle syntax and not tested. Just for a guidance.)

Comment: No, I need to use pagination so I need to write two different queries to get values and the count.

Comment: Here you could leave out the countQuery. You should not even need an @Query at all... 

            Result should work with`Page<String> findAllUniqueC(Pageable pageable,@Param("param") String param);`

Comment: The provided query + countQuery should work, maybe you oversimplified it here?

Comment: yes there are few more params involved but issue is still the same, in order by filter, additional column U is being added which is why I am getting the error

Comment: What is `C`? Sounds like it is a reference to another entity/embeddable and not a primary mapping to a single column. You are writing a JPQL not a SQL query remember that!

Comment: C is a column in the table t, it is not a primary key column, it is not a foreign key as well.

Comment: I realized why column U is being added in order by, I have `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(filterOption.getPageNo(), filterOption.getPageSize(), Sort.Direction.DESC, U);` in my code so it is being added to the order by field, is there a way to apply this sort after query has returned?

Comment: How would you sort on something that isn't in the result, after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only needed the unique values in column C and it's count so I applied the sort over C itself and removed it from the query. `order by` is auto applied during execution. Code snippets are as following:

```
 Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(filterOption.getPageNo(), filterOption.getPageSize(), Sort.Direction.DESC, C);


 // repository class
 @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT t.C FROM table t WHERE t.param = :param",
 countQuery = "SELECT count(DISTINCT t.C) FROM table t WHERE t.param = :param")
 Page<String> findUniqueWithCountPagination(Pageable pageable,
 @Param("param") String param);
```